# Звук [ж'] в современном русском языке

Tags: орфоэпия

Недавно, не без удивления обнаружил, что слово "подъезжай" я произношу с мягким ж. Потом данный звук услышал в речи диктора из фильма "Битва за Москву". В настоящее время звук [ж'] норма или диалект? И если норма, то какие ещё слова произносятся с этим звуком?

Comment: я тоже так говорю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще к вожжам и дрожжам допустимо дожди [дож'(ж')и], указанное подъезжай и подобные, и другие случаи на стыке морфем и слов: "хвощ зеленый" [вож'(ж')з'и] и проч.

Но настораживает что по упомянутому словарю вожжи и дрожжи разошлись в нормативном произношении. Я поостерегусь следовать подобным советам. На самом деле мягкий вариант устаревает и там и там.

(+)
Возникла необходимость пояснить пример "хвощ зеленый".
Этот ни на что здесь не претендует, кроме как показать, откуда может возникнуть мягкий звук Ж в современном русском. Ну или почти современном, поскольку нижесказанное на все 100 процентов относится к фонетике полувековой давности.

Начнем с того, что звук Щ - долгий мягкий шипящий. В отличие от кратких шипящих, он сохранил мягкость с тех времен, когда все шипящие были мягкими. 
На стыке слов в русском регулярно происходит регрессивная ассимиляция по нескольким параметрам - звонкости/глухости прежде всего. Эта ассимиляция обязательная при быстром темпе речи.
Однако ассимиляции по палатализации (твердости/мягкости) на стыках слов обычно не наблюдается. Также обычно не происходит изменения "долготы" согласного (хотя  это изменение и не исключено совершенно).  Также наблюдается переход свистящих в шипящие, но не наоборот. 
Таким образом, Щ в сочетании "хвощ зеленый" озвончается, возможно стягивается до одинарного звука, но сохраняет качество шипящего и палатализованного согласного. А это по всем признаком есть [Ж'Ж'] или [Ж']. Вот всё. Ни о каком "слиянии", ни о каких других далеко идущих выводах тут и речи нет.

Остается только добавить, что в современном языке этот "долгий Ж" постепенно теряет свою мягкость (историческая "петербургская норма", если не ошибаюсь). Но это очень длительный процесс, может и назад отыграть, ибо парный к нему по глухости-звонкости согласный Щ свою мягкость терять не намерен.

Comment: Ещё  на  моей  памяти  двойное  "ж"  стали  произносить  мягко. И  что,  устаревает  уже ?

Comment: Поздравляю, Вы хорошо сохранились для своих полутора тысяч лет.

Comment: *Хвощ зелёный* говорите? Мне кажется, что, когда звонкий идёт за глухим, слияния не должно происходить, а если наоборот (з-г), з-з или г-г, то оно вполне уместно. Например *выво**з ш**ёлковых платков.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой не совсем понимаю смісл вашей реплики. Здесь вообще-то о слиянии ничего не говорилось. Говорилось - и то косвенно - об явлении, называемом ассимиляцией. Ну и о палатализации шипящих. Я дополню ответ разбором этого примера. .

Comment: Простите, behemothus, я в терминологии не разбираюсь хорошо, вот и назвал слиянием. Да, я имел в виду палатализацию.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - ну в любом случае пример этот я разобрал. Что же касается терминологии, то в данном случае надо бы с ней поаккуратнее, ибо возможна грандиозная путаница, это явления совершенно разные  Палатализвция - это всего лишь артикуляционный прием извлечения определенной группы звуков, в русском языке известных как "мягкие". Ну и исторический процесс позиционно-обусловленного перехода твердых в мягкие (с заменой других качеств  обычно). Ваша реплика по-прежнему не слишком понятна.

Comment: Если для вас это важно, поясните на примерах, что там по вашему мнению происходит с этими парами С-С, С-Г Г-Г.  У меня так четко [хвож'(ж')з'ил'оный]

Comment: То есть у вас с "хвощом" происходит озвончение? Пожалуй, вы правы, это тоже вполне естественно. Простите, что непонятно получилось, под З и Г я имел в виду звонкие и глухие согласные, что происходит на стыке их. То есть, на мой ненаучный взгляд, если согласные разные, происходит их оглушение или озвончение по образцу **более поздней согласной** (из второго слова). А если одинаковые (обе зв. или гл.), то первая может превращаться во вторую. Прав я или нет? Как, например, в другом случае с приставкой и корнем. Говорим мы *вошшествие* (восшествие) или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *То есть у вас с "хвощом" происходит озвончение?* Да, конечно, это безусловная фонетическая норма. При слитной речи - без вариантов.

Comment: *Да, конечно, это безусловная фонетическая норма.* Ну и отлично! Буду знать теперь. :) А что скажете по поводу других моих рассуждений?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Одна хитрость, впрочем есть, но она имеет общий характер. Согласный В/Ф занимает особое положение во всей схеме русской ассимиляции, он как бы "не совсем согласный", в частности обычно не ассимилирует предшествующий согласный по звонкости, но этот факт известен и не оговаривается особо. Ну и подчеркну, что речь идет именно о слитном произношении, если есть хоть малейшая пауза между словами, то реггрессивной ассимиляции может и не происходить. В частности - при определенного типа скоплении согласных.

Comment: *Как, например, в другом случае с приставкой и корнем. Говорим мы вошшествие (восшествие) или я ошибаюсь?* - нет, не ошибаетесь. Это и есть регрессивная ассимиляция. Её законы в уелом одинаковы для случаев появления подобных пар на стыках слов, морфем и даже внутри морфа.   В данном случае - предшествующий свистящий переходит в шипящий. В в примерах типа "сжечь" происходит сразу две ассимиляции - с переходит в Ж. Совсем уж весело с новоделом "вещьдоки"  - там можно насчитать аж три ассимиляции. Это именно тот же случай, что и с исходным "хвощом."

Comment: На этом, пожалуй надо закончить, а то движок активно ругается. Или открывайте отдельную тему, всю теорию ассимиляции я вам тут все равно не изложу. Да и я сам не в лучшей форме, признаться...

Answer (score 3):

Вожжи [допуст. Ж'Ж'], дрожжи [допуст. ЖЖ]. Так в орфоэпическом словаре Т.Ф. Ивановой 2008. Ещё вспомнила Жюль и ЖЮРИ [ЖУ и допуст. устар. ЖЮ] Там же.

Comment: Я вариает [дрожжы] никогда не слышал

Answer (score 1):

попозже (попожж'е), визжит (вижж'ит), дребезжит (дребежж'ит), раньше говорили дожди (дожж'и)

Comment: Не только раньше, Пугачева и сейчас поёт [дожь] [дожж'и], причем последнее у неё рифмуется со [жди].

Answer (score 0):

*И если норма, то какие ещё слова произносятся с этим звуком?*

Мягкое произношение — один из вариантов, который раньше был основным, а теперь, к сожалению, устаревает. Кто придерживается его, произносят так же ***зажжёт*** (подожжёт, зажжённый), ***приезжий*** и другие. Кроме того, встречается произношение *подож'жи* ("подожди"), и совсем устаревает, но ещё можно услышать *рож'жение* и *рож'жество* ("рождение" и "Рождество"). Из производных от "дождя" (упомянутые *дощ* и *дож'жи*) ещё можно назвать *дож'жик* и *дож'жичек* ("дождик" и "дождичек").